# Rails 3.0 iPhone session

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3

I create a session passing user id and password to  a rails 3.0 server.
In

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

I get the allHeaderFields dictionary from the response and it has a "Set-Cookie" value.

```
"Set-Cookie" = "_quest_svr_session=BAh7ByIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlNDRmOTUyZmI2OTZlZTIzMDdlZDg2ZmI5ZTZhM2E4YTA6E3JlbWVtYmVyX3Rva2VuWwdpBiJFMDE1ZjE5OWJkMzU2YzMwNzE2ZjAxMTVhMzI4OTI0MzY3ODU0OTJmZTIyZmE3ZDFmZjdhM2ZiMDdlODFhZWZjMA%3D%3D--38aa7c663ccf53ddd39a0ded89c6f87da5b2abad; path=/; HttpOnly";
```

I store the value in

```
NSString * session_token =[dictionary objectForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];
```

When I create an NSMutableURLRequest I set the cookie value to the store session token

```
[theRequest setValue:session_token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

The problem is that the rails server is doing a redirect to the sign in page in the rails controller I use

```
before_filter :authenticate, :except => [ :new, :create, :templates]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to handle this manually. From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-156642):

> The URL loading system automatically sends any stored cookies appropriate for an NSURLRequest. unless the request specifies not to send cookies. Likewise, cookies returned in an NSURLResponse are accepted in accordance with the current cookie acceptance policy.

NSMutableURLRequest also has the method

```
- (void)setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:(BOOL)handleCookies
```

But the default value is `YES`, so again you shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: It is sending the token to the server I added this code to verify it

Comment: NSArray *pCookies=[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
        NSLog(@"cookies %@",[pCookies description] ); and I see the 
    "<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:@\"_quest_svr_session\" value:@\"BAh7ByIPc2VM4MGQ0MjE6E ... yX3Rva2VuWwdpBiJFMDE1ZjE5OWJkMzU2YzMwNzE2ZjAxMTVhMzI4OTI0MzY3ODU0OTJmZTIyZmE3ZDFmZjdhM2ZiMDdlODFhZWZjMA%3D%3D--4af272d0511d6c4d64119c26f7cbabe0777b0d10\" expiresDate:@\"(null)\" created:@\"335300065.000000\" sessionOnly:TRUE domain:@\"192.168.1.102\" path:@\"/\" secure:FALSE comment:@\"(null)\" commentURL:@\"(null)\" portList:[]>"